# sed or awk to get a string

Tags: bash, sed, awk, string

I have a shell script with

```
string=<deploymentTargets xmi:type="appdeployment:ClusteredTarget" xmi:id="ClusteredTarget_143378365
7353" name="cluster1"/>
```

I want the value between `name="` and `"/>` which is cluster1. This output should be stored to another variable.

Comment: I don't understand. You have to make your question more clear.

Comment: Use an XML parser to parse XML data.

Comment: Thanks for replying. To be more precise, i have a variable in my script as below:

string=<deploymentTargets xmi:type="appdeployment:ClusteredTarget" xmi:id="ClusteredTarget_143378365
7353" name="cluster1"/>

I want the value between name=" and "/> which is cluster1.

Comment: Only for this example: `cut -d \" -f 6 file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the specific example you show, all of these will save `cluster1` in the variable `$name`:

1. `sed`

   ```
   name=$(sed 's/.*="\(.*\)".*/\1/' <<<$string )
   ```
2. GNU `grep` (compiled with PCRE support)

   ```
   name=$(grep -oP '[^"]+(?="/>)'<<<$string )
   ```
3. Perl

   ```
   name=$(perl -pe 's/.*="(.*)".*/\1/' <<<$string )
   ```

If your shall doesn't support the `<<<` operator, change your preferred approach to using `printf` or `echo` instead:

```
name=$(printf '%s' "$string" | sed 's/.*="\(.*\)".*/\1/')
name=$(printf '%s' "$string" | grep -oP '[^"]+(?="/>)')
name=$(printf '%s' "$string" | perl -pe 's/.*="(.*)".*/\1/')
```

**IMPORTANT**: this will *only* work on the example you show. For more complex XML structures, including nested tags etc, you really should use a dedicated XML parser.

Comment: thanks cyrus and terdon. Cyrus the name=$(printf '%s' "$string" | sed 's/.*="\(.*\)".*/\1/') worked in my case.

Comment: Also can you suggest a good and easy source to learn sed and awk?

Comment: @vamsivegesna not really, no. Try `man sed` and `man awk` and search for their online documentation.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU grep:

```
a="$(grep -oP 'name="\K[^"]*(?="/>)' file)"
echo "$a"
```

With GNU sed:

```
a="$(sed -E 's|.*name="([^"]*)"/>.*|\1|' file)"
echo "$a"
```

Output:

```
cluster1
```